# Nginx ingress controller auto call api

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I just setup nginx ingress controller for my k8s cluster but i figured out 1 thing, the nginx controller automatically call the api many times(every seconds it calls about 10 times) to check something, is it a normal behavior?

This is from the log:

```
10.224.0.113 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 100 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 f89290e23c48fe9e4f782c530e3b6b07
10.224.1.75 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 187 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 232d6a6f705d271e4e4c6cf43a8873a5
10.224.0.222 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 189 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 5cc36a43c4925e0014a6f4ed9c8e04f9
10.224.1.75 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 98 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 b8ad122b968a575aad66e453b85f69de
10.224.0.222 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 100 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 8669e672c2b71c010ba5d9343f136e73
10.224.0.4 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 185 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 dbb5928e9eb9da559503feb4e6ba20d8
10.224.0.113 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 189 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 25112b68d1de0dee50a7a37c1ac30f7a
10.224.0.4 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 98 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 c60b5d6b5263bc266dc642f9258a6638
10.224.0.113 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 100 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 c423d9d9f6077bea9d34f601ab160173
10.224.1.75 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 187 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 ee199738f3142f14bac576d2efe72dd4
10.224.0.222 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 189 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 113eb7419c0baafcd8dac36a80355a42
10.224.1.75 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 98 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 e38cf253be8e87003e0b695b3d74f147
10.224.0.222 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 100 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 6145db51affc51a38a29aa851cd141f0
10.224.0.4 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 185 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 e87a409cc537817f81d183d875caa971
10.224.0.113 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:41:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 189 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 6d6423689ff5164f4fe270fc36a41eb6
10.224.0.4 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:42:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 98 0.002 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.002 200 03002fef8401eeeba3066816880026ef
10.224.0.113 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:42:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 100 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 569b3bf0db5b7941a022bedf5518e034
10.224.1.75 - - [09/Feb/2024:01:42:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 629 "-" "Load Balancer Agent" 187 0.001 [fg-local-aks-helloworld-one-80] [] 10.224.1.52:80 629 0.001 200 5e807ef841f507ddfeb3ae112291d7dc
```

I tried to search but there is no luck on the documentation on this.

Comment: guessing its some sort of health check to see if your api pod is available

Comment: Indeed, check if your Pod has a [liveness or a readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) configured on route `/`. If so it's an expected behavior.